Ошибка при упаковании бота через PyInstaller
Написал ТГ бота на aiogram3, с интерфейсом на PyQt, все делал через pyinstaller, а именно
pyinstaller --name bot --onefile --noconsole --hidden-import pydantic_core --hidden-import pydantic_core._pydantic_core bot.py

выбивает ошибка

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Первое - такая картинка с ошибкой - ни о чём. Неужели нельзя было скопировать текст? Второе - программа должна работать в автономном режиме, запуск в ОС должен проходить без проблем. Тогда будет работать и автономная сборка. Третье - игры со скрытыми импортами оставьте в стороне. Иначе проблемы будут и далее. Четвёртое - опция --onefile - плохая идея. --onedir - оптимальное решение. Пятое - ненужные опции понатаканы, а нужные нет.
